# Am I getting any added security by running wcf service on localhost?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I've inherited a relatively low traffic web application in which the main website is accessible on intranet, however it gets its data from a wcf service that runs on the same server which is only accessible via localhost. It was explained to me that this design was implemented as a security measure - essentially to ensure that no entity external to the server could potentially have access to our service and hence our data. The database however, is usually located on a different server.

It's been ok for a while but I am looking at ways to improve performance and it seems that running queries against the wcf service and having to serialize the response for transmission etc. is a waste of time - I'd like to just access the db directly from my web app.

Is this current design logical? Wouldn't it be better overall (for security, and performance) to have my site access db directly, and beef up the security between the app and the db?

Thanks in advance.

Rusty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have the big picture from your description. However, it is a common practise to have web-applications consuming content from more than a service to form a graphical interface to end-user. With the grow of SOA, this allows for fast integration to combine sources (from services) and producing rich output. This is called Mashup

This also, amongst other things, enhances the security of the backend services as they are only accessed by the backend application server, and not directly from front-end client

So, from an architectural perspective, it seems your application is trying to do this.

Having the services on the same server, and only consumed by the local server (localhost) is a choice taken to prevent but the application server running on the same machine from having access. This could be due to lack of better control on network access and network zoning

Your database lives on a different server, where there could be another measure implemented to secure the traffic and access

In general, implementation of security requires a budget, as any other functional and non-functional requirement. This is usually associated with the risk you're exposed to, and the sensitivity of the information. The earlier the security is built into the overall architecture the better.

Accessing the database from your web-application requires best practices to protect against the many risks of intrusions and vulnerabilities. In general, your web-client should NOT access the DB directly, and should always use server-side services and validation to do so, be it through wcf or other means

Comment: Thank you for this response, gives me a little to think about. I'm now responsible for this application so I need to be able to understand the current architecture so I can either support it or scrap it. Sounds like it is not as unusual of a setup as I thought. 

One clarification though is that my main web app (that at the moment gets its data from the localhost wcf service) is a *website* running on the server in IIS. Is it really that unsafe to give this site direct access to the database?

Comment: By implementing best code practises, you can minimize the risk. Have a look at: http://www.peterviola.com/blocking-sql-injection-with-iis-request-filtering/